# xsd parsing in python

Tags: python, xml, xsd

I have an xdr file and its format is described as an xsd.  So I need to parse the xsd file first.  Is there a python tool that will parse an xsd and give me the individual fields and their types.

An example of an xsd file I am trying to parse is here: http://mibs.cablelabs.com/namespaces/DOCSIS/3.0/xsd/ipdr/DOCSIS-SAMIS-TYPE-1/DOCSIS-SAMIS-TYPE-1_3.5.1-A.1.xsd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to look at this guy, for starters:

https://pypi.org/project/xmlschema/

Never had occasion to use it myself before, but it looks powerful and awesome.

Note this feature:

> Decoding of XML data into Python data and to JSON

As described in the example:

> Using a schema you can also decode the XML documents to nested
>   dictionaries, with values that match to the data types declared by the
>   schema.

I think you might want to give that lib a whirl.

Now, as to the best way to get familiar with the schema, as I assume is your goal here, why not try generating a sample instance using an XML editor like oXygen, for example, and then using the above to see what all is in there?

You might also try:

https://pypi.org/project/generateDS/

Hope this helps!